# When defining the operator ==, null value returns "call is ambiguous"

Tags: c#, null, call, operator-keyword, ambiguous

I have custom classes Rational, Real, and Complex.  In Complex I overload operators that allow me to compare a Complex and a Real, or a Complex and a Rational.  It would be easy if I could define an implicit cast of a Rational to a Complex, say, but for reasons not worth going into, I can't.

Therefore I have, among others,

`==(Complex a, Real b)`

and also

`==(Real a, Complex b)`

Obviously when I try to compare

`c==null`

I get the error message that the call is ambiguous.  I saw on a related thread the idea that I could just define `==(Complex a, object b)`  I had thought of that, but then if I want to allow symmetry, I also need `==(object a, Complex b)` in which case a comparison between two complexes will also be ambiguous.

Right now when I check for null I'm having to cast the Complex to an object first.  What's a better solution?  (I'm hoping for a general solution rather than a solution that depends on any relationship between the classes e.g. inheritance.)

Comment: show me your `classes declaration` code plz

Comment: Rahul, I'm really looking for a solution that's independent of class specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should probably post that I don't think there is a solution, and I just decided to forsake symmetry and go with ==(Complex a, object b).  Thanks to everyone who posted!

Answer (score 0):

Why to use the second overload? Are you sure you cannot use first one for your checks? There is no "good-looking" solution you are looking for.

Comment: It's out of an aesthetic desire for symmetry, so that I can compare `myReal == myComplex` or `myComplex == myReal`.  Obviously I can sacrifice symmetry; I'm wondering if there's a nice solution without having to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have something like `==(Complex c, Real C)` and `==(Complex c, Complex C)`, of course the compiler won't know which one to choose, so when you compare to a null you have to cast it like `c1 == (Complex) null`.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the rest of my post?  I've been having to cast in that fashion, and I'm looking for a cleaner solution.